# click event with each loop on dynamicly added elements javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, each

my problem is that the `$('input[name=isDefault]').length` equal `2`, but the each runs ony ones.

```
$(saveProduct).click(function (e) {
    $('input[name=isDefault]').each(function (index) {
       var that = this;
       console.log(index, 'index');
       console.log($('input[name=isDefault]').length);
       // do something...
    })
})
```

`$('input[name=isDefault]')` is dynamicly addes obj during another logic. 
I know there is a solution like `$(upper container).on("event", dynamic obj inside upper container)` - but this causes the click event to be almost everywhere, because `.on` is attaching event on `big area container`

**EDIT:**
I made some changes for testing purpose:

```
var imgs = imgs = $('div[name=fileContainer]');
console.log('before loop', imgs.length); // = 1
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    console.log('inside loop', imgs.length); // = 1
    //do something - imgs is dynamicly added html element by jquery, when I load page there is 1 element with that name
}
```

,but when I write `$('div[name=fileContainer]').length;` in console it's equal `2` (of course when I dynamicly added + 1 fileContainer element)

**EDIT:**
this isn't the answer, but I omitted the need to use the above loop.
Elsewhere in the code, I already have `$(something).on("change", dynamiclyAddedElements function() {})` with difrent main purpouse..., but! there I add addintional function where I created javascipt obj with needed data. Then I can use them in above `click` event.

Comment: $($'input[name=isDefault] The second $ is needed?

Comment: that should be `$('input[name="isDefault"]')`

Comment: sorry this is typo, the real code is difrent, I tryid to copy case simply - edited

Comment: So, for conclusion, are you good?

Answer (score 0):

> $(upper container).on("event", dynamic obj inside upper container) - but this causes the click event to be almost everywhere, because .on is attaching event on big area container

thats not right, you can use the second parameter to specify the selector

e.g

```
$('#upper_container').on('click', '.saveProduct', function(){...})
```

will add the click handler to (also dynamically added) `.saveProduct` and not `#upper_container` as you claim